# uitableview scroll to top on data's first load

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am using reloadData() to load tableview data but my table view on its first load scrolls to top when it's loading data  [like so ...](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IjjsTl81sVyp1HYBDxbEANdQaLojh_VA) and that's not so nice to the user experience. Does anybody of you know the solution guys to stop this behavior. Thank you for your help !
I getting users from firebase and I am loading the images like so :

```
 func getUsersFromFirebase(){
    refUsers.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let usersNbr = snapshot.childrenCount
        var counter = 0
        var newUsers: [User] = []
        for item in snapshot.children {
            counter = counter + 1
            let newitem:DataSnapshot = item as! DataSnapshot
            let user = User(snapshot: item as!DataSnapshot,uid:newitem.key.description)
            var newWishlists:[WishList]=[]                self.refProducts.child(newitem.key.description).observeSingleEvent(of : DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                for item in snapshot.children {
                    let newItem:DataSnapshot = item as! DataSnapshot
                    let newWishlist=WishList.init(snapshot: newItem)
                    if(newWishlist.products.count != 0 && !newWishlist.name.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).isEmpty){
                        newWishlists.append(newWishlist)
                    }
                }
                user.wishLists=newWishlists
                if(!(user.name=="" || user.image=="" ) ){
                    print("user privacy 1: " + user.isPrivate.description)
                    if(!user.isPrivate && user.wishLists.count != 0){
                        if(!user.isPrivate){
                            newUsers.append(user)
                        }
                    }
                }
                    self.firebaseUsers = newUsers.shuffled()
                    GlobalVar.isAppFirstLoad=false

                    GlobalVar.allUsers = self.firebaseUsers
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.reload(tableView: self.usersTableView)
                        print("user tableview reloaded 1")
                    }

            })

        }

    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDs(for: self.usersTableView, animated: true)
    }
}
    func reload(tableView: UITableView) {
        let contentOffset = tableView.contentOffset
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)

    }
```

I found the trick and its the .shuffled() that cause the behavior I think the array still shuffling when the tableview is reloading the data. 
So anyone of you knows how the check if the array has finished shuffling?

Comment: post some code i think you maust be doing anything wrong its not a default behavior

Comment: what is in this ? 
self.reload(tableView: self.usersTableView)

Comment: it lets the tableview to reload without scrolling to top when a user has already scrolled please check the edit

Answer (score 0):

So if you check in your code  you have flag

```
 GlobalVar.isAppFirstLoad=false
```

If you think with commom sense why it exist? you should check for 
if condition that contains `GlobalVar.isAppFirstLoad` this value as true and in its block their will be some code that will be scrolling tableView to top.

Find it and remove it.

Comment: Hey Abu, thank you for your reply I found the cause please check the edit

Comment: yes remove this line 
 tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)